# Binary Search Tree post-order Iterator

Tags: php, algorithm, iterator, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing an AVL Tree (a self-balancing Binary Search Tree) in PHP and have things working pretty normally.  I have in-order, pre-order, and level-order *iterators* working, but I can't figure out how to do a post-order iterator for a BST.  Google searches turn up how to do an iterative post-order traversal, but not an iterator.

So far my only success has been to use a post-order traversal to build an array and then return an array iterator.  This is bad because it iterates the tree twice and adds more space complexity.

**What is the general algorithm for building a post-order iterator?**

*The only reason the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag is here is that iterators in PHP are different from the ones in Java or C++. It might affect your advice.*

*Also, if PHP had generators, this would be a breeze because the post-order traversal could simply yield values, turning it into an iterator . . .*

**Edit:** here is the in-order iterator implementation. Maybe it can help you understand what I want from a post-order iterator:

```
class InOrderIterator implements Iterator {

    /**
     * @var ArrayStack
     */
    protected $stack;

    /**
     * @var BinaryNode
     */
    protected $root;

    /**
     * @var BinaryNode
     */
    protected $value;

    public function __construct(BinaryNode $root) {
        $this->stack = new ArrayStack;
        $this->root = $root;
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function current() {
        return $this->value->getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.next.php
     * @return void
     */
    public function next() {
        /**
         * @var BinaryNode $node
         */
        $node = $this->stack->pop();

        $right = $node->getRight();
        if ($right !== NULL) {
            // left-most branch of the right side
            for ($left = $right; $left !== NULL; $left = $left->getLeft()) {
                $this->stack->push($left);
            }
        }

        if ($this->stack->isEmpty()) {
            $this->value = NULL;
            return;
        }
        $this->value = $this->stack->peek();

    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.key.php
     * @return NULL
     */
    public function key() {
        return NULL; //no keys in a tree . . .
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function valid() {
        return $this->value !== NULL;
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.rewind.php
     * @return void
     */
    public function rewind() {
        $this->stack->clear();

        for ($current = $this->root; $current !== NULL; $current = $current->getLeft()) {
            $this->stack->push($current);
        }

        $this->value = $this->stack->peek();
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds really weird cause if you can implement pre-order and in-order then what's the problem of running post-order ? it's just a change of the order of the recursive calls to the children. post-order is: go over the right  child and its children, then on the left-child and it's children and last print "self"

Comment: @alfasin I'm not doing recursion. Please reread the question.  I'm making an iterator, not traversing the tree.

Comment: I guess that if you'll show us some code it could be clearer

Comment: @alfasin I added the in-order traversal example, maybe it will help you understand what I'm after.

Comment: Nice! can you show us the pre-order and a usage example ?

Comment: I checked the manual an hour ago - it's not helpful. A full example that includes usage will be better, I don't mind playing with it for a bit - I LOVE this kind of stuff. And who knows, I might be able to help you ;)

Comment: @alfasin https://github.com/morrisonlevi/PHP-Datastructures Feel free to check it out.  Run `AVLTreeExample.php` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ALMOST convert an example of an iterative traversal in C++ into an iterator. [Latest on github](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent/blob/master/src/Ardent/AvlTree.php).  Still need to figure out a few cases.

```
class PostOrderIterator implements Iterator {

    /**
     * @var ArrayStack
     */
    protected $stack;

    /**
     * @var BinaryNode
     */
    protected $root;

    /**
     * @var BinaryNode
     */
    protected $value;

    protected $current;

    public function __construct(BinaryNode $root) {
        $this->stack = new ArrayStack;
        $this->root = $root;
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function current() {
        return $this->current->getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.next.php
     * @return void
     */
    public function next() {
        /**
         * @var BinaryNode $node
         */
        if ($this->value !== NULL) {
            $right = $this->value->getRight();
            if ($right !== NULL) {
                $this->stack->push($right);
            }
            $this->stack->push($this->value);
            $this->value = $this->value->getLeft();
            $this->next();
            return;
        }

        if ($this->stack->isEmpty()) {
            $this->current = $this->value;
            $this->value = NULL;
            return;
        }

        $this->value = $this->stack->pop();

        $right = $this->value->getRight();
        if ($right !== NULL && !$this->stack->isEmpty() && ($right === $this->stack->peek())) {
            $this->stack->pop();
            $this->stack->push($this->value);
            $this->value = $this->value->getRight();
            $this->current = $this->value;
        } else {

            if ($this->current === $this->value) {
                $this->value = NULL;
                $this->next();
            } else {
                $this->current = $this->value;
                $this->value = NULL;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.key.php
     * @return NULL
     */
    public function key() {
        return NULL; //no keys in a tree . . .
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.valid.php
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function valid() {
        return $this->current !== NULL;
    }

    /**
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.rewind.php
     * @return void
     */
    public function rewind() {
        $this->stack->clear();

        $this->value = $this->root;
        $this->next();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to describe the algorithm or justify what it is doing, but hopefully over time it will make sense.